# MySQL date compare problem?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM shortleavedetails WHERE employee_code='17' AND 
(DATE(authorizeddate) <= DATE(2011-1-1) AND DATE(authorizeddate) >= DATE(2010-5-1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM shortleavedetails WHERE employee_code='17' AND  authorizeddate between '2010-5-1'and '2011-1-1'
```

Comment: It's better to cast to DATE as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897133/mysql-select-date-range-issue/4897195#4897195).

Answer (score 2):

Put your date values in single quotes as they are literal strings, otherwise MySQL can't tell that's a date and not the number (2011 MINUS 1 MINUS 1 = 2009).

You don't need the DATE() casts around them either.

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  shortleavedetails
WHERE
  employee_code = '17'
AND
  (DATE(authorizeddate) <= '2011-01-01'
   AND
   DATE(authorizeddate) >= '2010-05-01')
```

Comment: There's no need to use the DATE function - the implicit conversion on the dates as strings will be as of midnight for those dates.  In fact, using the DATE function in this example means that an index on (or including/convering) the `authorizeddate` column can't be used.

Comment: The meaning of that query would be different. Without `DATE`, an authorizeddate of '2011-01-01 13:50' would not match while with `DATE` it will as only the date portion of the datetime is compared.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM shortleavedetails WHERE employee_code='17' AND 
(authorizeddate<='2011-1-1' AND authorizeddate >= '2010-5-1')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM shortleavedetails WHERE employee_code='17' AND 
authorizeddate <= '2011-01-01' AND authorizeddate >='2010-05-01'
```