# Interpreting Dates using MySql/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a database with stuff about purchases from my site. I have the date and time sold stored in the following format

```
2012-04-23 16:29:28
```

Now what I have this currently for getting products that a certain person has purchased:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `purchases` WHERE `ReceiverKey` LIKE '4da0e081-320d-4c7b-bf5b-3d9f022d21d3' AND `InventoryName` LIKE '[Dugley] Cache Clearer 2.0' LIMIT 0, 30 ") or die(mysql_error());
```

However I need to sort the *When* column to only show purchases within the last 30 days.

Any ideas on how to do this efficiently? Code examples would be appreciated as I suck at dates.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to modify your SQL query to [only return rows with a certain date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4426083/901048)?

Comment: Your "following format" is only relevant if you're storing your date's as strings and not the correct date time column type.

Comment: Why do you use `LIKE` for an exact comparison? Use `=` for this purpose!

Comment: Well SELECT * FROM purchases` WHERE ReceiverKey LIKE '4da0e081-320d-4c7b-bf5b-3d9f022d21d3' AND InventoryName LIKE '[Dugley] Cache Clearer 2.0' AND When > NOW()+30 day LIMIT 0, 30 ;` Returns an error

Comment: @Dagon date<NOW()+30 day ? Really?

Comment: my bad, to early in the morning - WHERE when > (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE when > date_add(NOW(), interval -30 days)
```

Comment: ..or just WHERE when > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAYS